# How to measure text in a RichTextBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to get the height necessary to display the full text in my RichTextBox (when the text extends beyond the set height of the control).

Reminder: Silverlight has no handy TextRenderer.MeasureText like WPF does, nor any other apparent way to measure text.

Doesn't seem like there's any way to do this.  I've seen mention of people measuring text of a single font (not mixed as in my RichTextBox) by creating a TextBlock and getting it's Width.  Even this doesn't work - it's perfect for some fonts and inconsistent for others.

My app is occasionally connected, so I can't call the server.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, I don't think there's a good way to do this in Silverlight today.  There are some functions available in the Document Toolkit by First Floor Software, however those are geared towards working with XPS documents.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do, however in Silverlight 5 the RichTextBox does come with the ability to "overflow" text into multiple other RichTextBoxes when the first one cannot display all of the data.  This allows you to more easily create a multi-column text layout.

Document Toolkit: http://firstfloorsoftware.com/documenttoolkit

SL5 Video: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-5-multi-column-linked-text/

SL5 Blog Post: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/04/13/silverlight-5-advancements-in-text

Comment: If I was on SL5, I would simply PInvoke (app is running on windows only) and call the windows API GetTextExtent